# How to modify the coefficients of this parametric equation to mimick a heart/bean shape please?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, parametric

My current equation is:
(x(t), y(t)) = (1.53cos(t), 0.99sin(t)+0.42cos(2t))

From my understanding, this is an explicitly-defined parametric equation.
(See this screenshot for a visualized version of my equation:
[(x(t), y(t)) = (1.53cos(t), 0.99sin(t)+0.42cos(2t)) Plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XL27.png))

However, I would like to modify my equation to mimick a specific shape:
(See this screenshot:
[Heart or bean-shaped equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rEgK.png))

Can anyone please provide advice or guidance on how to modify my current equation to become more similar to the shape that I am aiming for? It does not have to be identical. It just needs to be similar to close enough. Thank you for the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that your target is not centered in the plane at all similarly to how your current parametric equation is centered, so you should think about what kind of extra coefficient(s) you would need to add to your function to compensate for that.

The next step is to sample your target to a list of numeric points, each point being a pair of (x,y) values. (For example, if the darker line in the center of the bean is at $x=0$, I estimate that (0, -1.7) is on the bean curve --- it is at the center of the indentation.)

The third step is called "fitting", see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). For this you need to think about how your problem translates into a system of equations based on your target points.

Then solve that system *as well as you can*. Ordinarily in such a problem, you will end up with more equations than you have variables --- this is called an "overdetermined system". In such a case, you will usually want to minimize some kind of sum of squares which represent your errors, and a powerful tool to minimize is looking at the [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_(mathematics)). Or alternatively, find software which does this for you.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and knowledge. Thank you for sharing.
1) My shape does not need to be perfectly identical or centered the same way as the "target" or "goal". I just want my equation to be similar in its shape, it does not have to be perfect or exact.
2) I am not too familiar with how to "sample" to a "list of numeric points" and then 3) fitting... would probably result in a totally different equation.

[I am hoping to modify the coefficients to mimick the shape of the "target", but after trying different constants, this was the best I got. Not sure if anyone has better ideas/tips]

Comment: To sample in your case is merely to estimate locations using the given grid in your target shape image. For example, if the darker line in the center of the bean is at $x$=0, I estimate that (0, -1.7) is on the bean curve. When you choose the points to estimate, understand that it is important that they be relatively equally spaced around your curve (many points which are all close to one another will not give the fitting process much extra data).

Comment: Fitting will not change your equation too much, if you make the variables you solve for the coefficients of functions you already use (or if you only add a few new functions). For example, start with $(k_1\cos(t), k_2\sin(t)+k_3\cos(2t))$ and perhaps maybe add $\cos(3t)$ term(s) also with extra variables as coefficients. Here you should think about how the symmetry of your target function fits with your equations, otherwise you will add variables which will end up being equal simply because of the symmetry.